# C pointer arithmetic and array access

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I have a function that takes a pointer to an array of structs

```
typedef struct {
    bool isUsed;
    int count;
} MyStructure;

void Process(MyStructure *timeStamps, int arrayLength){
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        MyStructure *myStructure = &(*(timeStamps + i));
        if (myStructure->isUsed == true){
          /*do something*/
        }
    }

}
```

The way that I am accessing the array seems to be a little off.

```
&(*(timeStamps + i))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `timeStamps` is of type `MyStructure*`, which means that this line:

```
MyStructure *myStructure = &(*(timeStamps + i));
```

is equivalent to:

```
MyStructure *myStructure = timeStamps + i;
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
MyStructure *myStructure = &timeStamps[i];
```

Note that in this expression: `&(*(timeStamps + i))`, the `timeStamps + i` is a pointer to the element at index `i` (i.e. the address of this element), which is then dereferenced by using [dereference operator (`*`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) that returns an l-value of type `MyStructure` and then you retrieve the address of this element by using the *address-of* operator (`&`) which is equal to the address that `timeStamps + i` held at the beginning.

Answer (score 6):

```
&(*(timeStamps + i))
```

is equivalent with

```
&timeStamps[i]
```

which is, in turn, simply

```
timeStamps + i
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

```
MyStructure *myStructure = &timeStamps[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I worked in C, but as far as I remember the square brackets indexing operator ([]) is the same as adding to the pointer. So:

`timeStamps[i]` should be equivalent to `*(timeStamps + i)`

Therefore you should be able to use

`myStructure = &timeStamps[i]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
void Process(MyStructure *timeStamps, int arrayLength){
    for (MyStructure *i = timeStamps; i < timeStamps + arrayLength; i++) {
        if (i->isUsed == true) {
```